# Variance and covariance in the context of deterministic variables

Tags: variance, covariance, random-variable, terminology, deterministic

**Questions**:

1. Can we talk about:
   *variance* of a deterministic variable?;
   *covariance* between a deterministic variable and a stochastic variable?;
   *covariance* between two deterministic variables?
2. Are these concepts well defined in sample?; in population?

**Motivation**
Take a simple regression

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \varepsilon.$$

Suppose the regressor $x$ is stochastic. The OLS estimate of $\beta_1$ will be

$$\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\widehat{\text{Cov}}(x,y)}{\widehat{Var}(x)}$$

where hats denote sample counterparts of the population concepts. No problem here.

Now suppose $x$ is deterministic. I am not sure if I can use terms like *variance* and *covariance* in this context. Should I exchange $\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\widehat{\text{Cov}}(x,y)}{\widehat{Var}(x)}$ for something like

$$\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$$

to be correct? But then again, how meaningful is $\bar{x}$ when $x$ is deterministic? So should I go all the way to

$$\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j)(y_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n y_j)}{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(x_i-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j)^2}?$$

I am picking on details here and this may not be too important; my main questions are listed at the top of the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**All five questions have "yes" answers**--but we have to be careful about what they mean.

1. **"Variance of a deterministic variable."**

   Let's understand a "deterministic variable" to be a univariate dataset.  It's just a bunch of values $X=x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, with no probability model.  By *definition* its variance is

   $$\text{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i - \bar X\right)^2$$

   where $$\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ is its *mean.*  There is no justification whatsoever to use $n-1$ instead of $n$ in any of these fractions--and this is never legitimately done--because no estimates are being made.

   We may always think of $X$ as defining a "population."  This is the definition of a population variance.
2. **"Covariance between a deterministic variable and a stochastic variable."**

   One way to understand this is to assume it refers to a sequence of the form $(x_1, Y_1), (x_2,Y_2), \ldots, (x_n,Y_n)$ where the $x_i$ are numbers and the $Y_i$ are random variables.  Then we may define the random variable $$\bar Y = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i,$$ *via* which the covariance of $x$ and $Y$ is defined as

   $$\text{Cov}(x,Y) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)(Y_i - \bar Y).$$

   It is a linear combination of the $Y_i$ and consequently is itself a random variable.  This notation is frequently used as a shorthand in linear regression calculations.
3. **"Covariance between two deterministic variables."**

   "Two deterministic variables" can be considered a dataset of ordered pairs $(x_1, y_1), (x_2,y_2), \ldots, (x_n,y_n)$.  The covariance can be defined exactly as in (2) and interpreted similarly.  In fact, this is a direct consequence of (1): after all, [covariances are variances](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142472).
4. **"Are these concepts well defined in samples?"**

   Because they are well-defined for any dataset, they are well-defined for a sample.  Note that similar expressions with $n-1$ in the (outer) denominator are *estimators*: they are *not* the sample variance or sample covariance.
5. **"Are these concepts well defined in populations?"**

   Because they are well-defined for any dataset, and a population can be considered a dataset (when fully enumerated), they are well-defined for a population.

Comment: Can you please explain how we would use these definitions to calculate the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ when $(X_i, Y_i)=(Z_1+i, Z_2+i)$ with $Z_1, Z_2 \overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ for deterministic $i=1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: @Statmerkur The bilinearity of covariance implies the addition of $i$ does not change the covariance, while the independence of the $Z_i$ implies that covariance must either be $0$ or undefined.  Because the $Z_i$ have finite variances, the covariance will be $0.$

Comment: Thank you. However, if I understand you correctly, the correlation estimate in this little `R` simulation `n <- 100; cor(rnorm(n) + 1:n, rnorm(n) + 1:n)` should be close to $0$  -- but it is actually close to $1$. The latter does make sense to me as the two sequences are identical up to a small noise component.  Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: @stat You don't understand correctly if you expect that correlation to be near $0,$ but I cannot guess what the nature of the misunderstanding might be.

Comment: I don't expect that correlation to be near $0$. Rather, I'm interested in how one would calculate the expected correlation in such a case. I was then confused about what you said above since, I thought, by the same reasoning the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ when $(X_i, Y_i)= (Z_{1,i}+i,Z_{2,i}+i)$ with $Z_{1,i}, Z_{2,i}\overset{\mathrm{i.i.d.}}{\sim}\mathcal{N}(0,1);i=1,\ldots,100$ would also have to be $0$. And I think the `R` code calculates the correlation in one particular realization of this sequence.

Comment: @Stat The rules of covariance continue to apply.  The `R` code treats `1:100` as the equivalent of its empirical distribution.  You can confirm this by computing the covariance directly or using bilinearity: `x <- rnorm(n);
y <- rnorm(n);
z <- 1:n;
(c(Covariance=cov(z+x, z+y), Sum=cov(z, z) + cov(z, y) + cov(z, x) + cov(x, y)))`

Comment: That makes sense to me. In your definition, the covariance between a deterministic variable and a random variable is itself a random variable. Taking expectations, we get $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)] = \mathrm{Var}(S)$ and $\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{Var}(X)]=\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{Var}(Y)]=1+\mathrm{Var}(S)$, where $S=1,\ldots,n$. But the expected correlation between $X$ and $Y$, as the expectation of a ratio distribution, doesn't seem to be immediately available. Am I right here?

Comment: @stat By definition, all covariances are *numbers.*

Comment: You wrote "the covariance of $x$ and $Y$ is defined as [...]. It is a linear combination of the $Y_i$ and consequently is itself a random variable." in your original answer. So I'm a little bit confused now.

Comment: @stat I agree.  Consider asking a specific question in a new thread.  Please note that the present thread concerns several distinct settings in which "covariance" has distinct meanings.  You have to pay attention to which setting you are in and what exactly you mean by "covariance"!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your first three questions is no: it makes no sense in general to talk about variance or covariance involving a deterministic variable.

However, if we begin with a deterministic variable but then use some method of imposing a probability distribution on it, it then becomes a random variable, and the concept of variance then makes sense. For example, any deterministic variable can become a random variable simply by imposing a degenerate (i.e., constant) distribution on it; in this case, the variance (along with its covariance with any other random variable) becomes 0.

A more interesting way of imposing a distribution on deterministic random variables is to use the empirical distribution, based on an observed sample. That is, if you observe $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in a sample, then we can define a discrete probability distribution on $x$ by $$P(x=x_0)=\frac1n \cdot\text{the number of $i$ such that $x_i=x_0$}$$
for all $x_0$. For example, in the case where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are all distinct, we get $P(x=x_i)=\frac1n$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$. If we use this probability distribution on $x$, then the mean of $x$ becomes simply the sample mean $\overline x=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and the variance of $x$ becomes $\hat\sigma^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2$.

This same idea can be applied in the situation where we have observed vectors $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$. We can define a joint probability distribution on $(x,y)$ again by using the empirical distribution, and the covariance between $x$ and $y$ then becomes $$\text{Cov}(x,y)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)(y_i-\overline y)$$